# Group 2D array by id column, push amount into group, and add amount to all previous amounts in group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

Using array_key_exists() you would find repeated values and be able to sum them up. In my case, I am not trying to sum all the values and consolidate them into one value. What I am trying to do is to iterate through the values, group by the `ac_no` value and each subsequent encounter of the same `ac_no` value, add the new `amount` to all previously encountered amounts in the group.

Here's my sample input:

```
$array = [
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => 0.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => 51255.11],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => -500.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => -621.05],
     ['ac_no' => 100002, 'amount' => .00],
     ['ac_no' => 100003, 'amount' => .00],
     ['ac_no' => 100004, 'amount' => 20714.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100004, 'amount' => 0.00]
];
```

Notice that `ac_no` value `100001` exists 4 times.  In the result, the `100001` group should have the following elements because each absolute value is added to all previous amounts in the group:

```
[
    52,376.05,    # .00 + 51255.11 + abs(-500.00) + abs(-621.05)
    52,376.05,    # 51255.11 + abs(-500.00) + abs(-621.05)
    1,120.94,     # abs(-500.00) + abs(-621.05)
    621.05        # abs(-621.05)
]
```

My current coding attempt looks like this:

```
foreach ($nameAndCode as $key => $vals) {
    if (array_key_exists($vals['ac_no'], $res)) {
        $amt = abs($vals['amount']);
        $res[$vals['ac_no']]['ac_no']  += $vals['ac_no'];
        $res[$vals['ac_no']]['amount'] += $amt; 
    } else {
        $res[$vals['ac_no']]  = $vals;
    }
}
```

Comment: What actual _result_ do you want to get from this, with the given input data?

Comment: Definitely need to see what you want this output to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three `foreach()` along with `array_sum()` and `is_array()` will do the job (I am considering negative values to be subtracted):

```
 $acNoWiseArray = [];
 
 //get all amounts as an array  ac_no wise
 foreach($array as $arr){
    $acNoWiseArray[$arr['ac_no']]['sum'][] = $arr['amount'];
 }
 
 
 $finalArray = [];
 foreach($acNoWiseArray as $key=>&$value){//calling by reference
    foreach($value['sum'] as $k=> $val){
        $finalArray[$key]['new_sum'][] = (is_array($value)) ? array_sum($value['sum']) : $value['sum'][$k];
        array_shift($value['sum']);
    }
 }
 
 print_r($finalArray);
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/duoEc

***Important Update:*** But as I looked at your calculation closely (based on @mickmackusa comment) I found that you are ignoring the `-` sign and adding all values as positive. To do so do like below:

```
$acNoWiseArray = [];
 
 foreach($array as $arr){
    $acNoWiseArray[$arr['ac_no']]['sum'][] = $arr['amount'];
 }
 
 
 $finalArray = [];
 foreach($acNoWiseArray as $key=>&$value){
    foreach($value['sum'] as $k=> $val){
        $finalArray[$key]['new_sum'][] = (is_array($value)) ? array_sum(array_map('abs',$value['sum'])) : abs($value['sum'][$k]);
        array_shift($value['sum']);
    }
   
    
 }
 
 print_r($finalArray);
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/j9tkC

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $result = array();

    $nameAndCode = array(
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100001,
            'amount' => .00
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100001,
            'amount' => 51255.11
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100001,
            'amount' => -500.00
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100001,
            'amount' => -621.05
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100002,
            'amount' => .00
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100003,
            'amount' => .00
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100004,
            'amount' => 20714.00
        ),
        array(
            'ac_no' => 100004,
            'amount' => .00
        ),
    );


    // init new array of arrays to store each amount of ac_no seprately
    $parsedArr = array();

    foreach ($nameAndCode as $_arr) {
        // iterate over data source 
        if (!isset($parsedArr[$_arr['ac_no']])) $parsedArr[$_arr['ac_no']] = array();
        // save to new, convenient array
        array_push($parsedArr[$_arr['ac_no']], $_arr['amount']);
    }

    // iterate over parsed array where each element is an array of values
    foreach ($parsedArr as $ac_no => $values) {
        // check if index in resulting array exist
        if (!isset($result[$ac_no])) $result[$ac_no] = array();
        // prep all_values sum index
        if (!isset($result[$ac_no]['ALL_VALUES'])) $result[$ac_no]['ALL_VALUES'] = 0;

        // iterate over each values in ac_no array; set iterator to current key and itarate at max 3 elements ahead
        foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
            for ($i = $key; $i < $key + 4; $i++) {
                // check if element exists
                if (!isset($result[$ac_no][$key])) $result[$ac_no][$key] = 0;
                // check if element exists
                if (isset($values[$i])) $result[$ac_no][$key] += abs($values[$i]);
            }
            $result[$ac_no]['ALL_VALUES'] += abs($val);
        }
    }
    print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

- While iterating each row, unconditionally push a new value into the group with a value of 0.
- Then force the amount value to be positive with abs().
- Then iterate all elements in the group, modify the values by reference, and increase each element by the current, unsigned amount.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gutWM))

```
$array = [
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => 0.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => 51255.11],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => -500.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100001, 'amount' => -621.05],
     ['ac_no' => 100002, 'amount' => .00],
     ['ac_no' => 100003, 'amount' => .00],
     ['ac_no' => 100004, 'amount' => 20714.00],
     ['ac_no' => 100004, 'amount' => 0.00]
];
 
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $result[$row['ac_no']][] = 0;
    $amount = abs($row['amount']);
    foreach ($result[$row['ac_no']] as &$cached) {
        $cached += $amount;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
    100001 => array (
        0 => 52376.16,
        1 => 52376.16,
        2 => 1121.05,
        3 => 621.05,
    ),
    100002 => array (
        0 => 0.0,
    ),
    100003 => array (
        0 => 0.0,
    ),
    100004 => array (
        0 => 20714.0,
        1 => 0.0,
    ),
)
```